# Using a DLL which in turn uses Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dll

We are using Entity Framework in a service library for my application but don't want to have a dependency on EF in any application which makes reference to this DLL. The problem we have is the main application has two problems:

1. It doesn't have the references to EntityFramework.dll (I think this is an MSBuild issue?)
2. I'm required to put the connection string in the main applications App.Config file

Are there any solutions for this or do we have to just accept any application using this DLL will require a NUGet install of EF?

Comment: "I'm required to put the connection string in the main applications App.Config file" And why is that a problem?

Comment: Its not a problem in the app.config file of the dll using EF. It is a problem in the consuming application that should not be aware of EF at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your library needs access to the code in the Entity Framework, it will need the code of the Entity Framework, provided by EntityFramework.dll.

If another application makes use of your library, it will therefore also need the code in the EntityFramework dll. You can't run code you don't have. The (transitive) dependency is unavoidable.

Comment: thanks but the consuming application doesn't need access to Entity Framework. It just needs to execute a service that uses EF to complete its action.

Comment: @JohnStack If it uses EF, it needs EF. You can't use EF without loading the dll, because that's where the EF code is.

Comment: Ah ok - so are we saying that the DLL doesn't compile itself into a neat little package with everything it needs? Therefore the EF code is a seperate dll that also needs to be installed in the main application and therefore cannot ever be avoided

Comment: @JohnStack you got it. Your library references the EF dll, but doesn't include it.

Comment: Dam! The penny's just dropped :)

Comment: @JohnStack you can use tools like [Fody/Costura](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) to embed referenced dlls in your dll to make a single distributed dll.

Answer (score 0):

> We are using Entity Framework in a service library for my application but don't want to have a dependency on EF in any application which makes reference to this DLL.

Then you need to split your library into classes that use EF and those that don't.  If your library uses EF then the app will need to reference it, otherwise you will get a missing reference error at run-time.

> I'm required to put the connection string in the main applications App.Config file

Yes, that's how *application* configuration works.  You configure the *application* (including all dependent libraries) in app.config.

Comment: Just to clarify - the service classes don't return any entity objects to the consuming application. The application itself has no need for these and only needs to know the return result confiming if the service completed its action or why it didn't. 
Therefore it seems annoying for any application using this service class to need EF. 

As for the app.config, there are ways around having to put the connection string in this. I didn't inlcude them in my original question as did't want to lead anyone down the same path as the current solution we have.

Answer (score 0):

Best case scenario you still need the connection string in your main config file. 
When you compile your project, your library dll gets copied over to the main bin folder. From then onward it will read the connection string details from the config file of your host application. Nothing you can do about that basically.

Now, if you want to not have a dependency on EF in your main project that is doable as well, but this means you cannot use any code which involves EF.

If you use a db first approach then EF will create model classes for your data. I prefer to not use those classes because they only exist in your EF context. You're better off using DTOs - Data Transfer Objects which live in a separate library for reuse purposes basically. Then you can swap from EF to something else easily should you need that. Keep in mind that this is not the main purpose, the main purpose is to achieve Separation of Concerns and not hardcode yourself into using any database layer.

So, use DTOs, make your library return data using those DTOs which means that your main app never needs to know anything about EF and you can drop the reference to it.

Here's an example of what I mean : https://eidand.com/2014/08/17/separation-of-concerns-application-layers/

Comment: Thanks for ther reply. I am already using DTO to transfer the request/result of the service which is why I'm confused as to why I still must use EF in the consuming application. 
Unfortunately I'm still having to install EF in the consuming application so I haven't seperated the concern as a result