# Create NuGet package for DLL using EF

Tags: vb.net, nuget, nuget-package

As a further question to my original one asked here....

[Using a DLL which in turn uses Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375876/using-a-dll-which-in-turn-uses-entity-framework)

Is it possible to create a NuGet package which would tie up all the lose ends?

I've followed some guides and have created my first package which includes the needed .dll files but I cannot figure out how to modify the App.Config of the Porject that installs the NuGet package. For example how would I make the following lines appear in the App.Config?

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="XYZ;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework> .... etc
</entityFramework>
```

If I can solve this I think that's a good solution for the problem we have were the DLL is used across multiple projects as it also gives us versioning with the packages.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.nuget.org/create/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations

Comment: No I somehow missed that. I've added a file called 'app.config.transform'. and added the new XML and it works - my installing application gets all the dependencies needed with a complete app.config so thanks!